# Increase the height of a UITextView

Tags: iphone

```
scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:
                        [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];

UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25, 100, 200, 250)];
    textView .text =@"long text ";
```

I will be getting some data of unknown length. to be added to the `UITextView` . Sometimes the height of the content of the text might exceed the height of the `UITextView` which is `250` (shown above).

How can i increase the height of the `UITextView` based on the text i receive ? I would appreciate a sample code?

note: according to my code i am defining the `width` and `height` of the `UITextView` before adding the text to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `NSString`'s `sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:` to get a `CGSize` struct telling you how big the text will be.

Usage:

```
CGSize size = [mystring sizeWithFont:[UIfont systemFontOfSize:15]
                   constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(200, CGFLOAT_MAX)
                       lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
[myTextView setFrame:CGRectMake(25,100,200,size.height)];
```